# Disable hover function on selection

Tags: jquery

I'm currently trying to build a thumbnail gallery that allows the user to highlight thumbnails from a certain category, but when no category is selected or thumbnails that are not highlighted, the highlight appears on hover.

Hover Function

```
$(window).load(function(){
$('.print, .campaign, .identity, .photography').each(function(){  
$(this).css('opacity', 0);
$(this).css('display', 'block');  
});  

$('.box_print, .box_campaign, .box_identity, .box_photography').hover(function(){  
$(this).children('.print, .campaign, .identity, .photography').stop().fadeTo(300, 4);  
},function(){  
$(this).children('.print, .campaign, .identity, .photography').stop().fadeTo(000, 0);  
}); 

});
```

Category functions

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".cat-all").click(function(){
    $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold')
    $(".cat-print, .cat-identity, .cat-photography, .cat-campaign").css('font-weight', 'normal')
    $(".print, .identity, .photography, .campaign").fadeTo(100, 0);
    $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
});

$(".cat-print").click(function(){
    $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold')
    $(".cat-all, .cat-identity, .cat-photography, .cat-campaign").css('font-weight', 'normal')      
    $(".print").fadeTo(600, 4);
    $(".identity, .photography, .campaign").fadeTo(100, 0);
    $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
});


$(".cat-identity").click(function(){
    $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold')
    $(".cat-all, .cat-print, .cat-photography, .cat-campaign").css('font-weight', 'normal')     
    $(".identity").fadeTo(600, 4);
    $(".print, .photography, .campaign").fadeTo(100, 0);
    $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
});


$(".cat-photography").click(function(){
    $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold')
    $(".cat-all, .cat-print, .cat-identity, .cat-campaign").css('font-weight', 'normal')        
    $(".photography").fadeTo(600, 4);
    $(".identity, .print, .campaign").fadeTo(100, 0);
    $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
});


$(".cat-campaign").click(function(){
    $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold')
    $(".cat-all, .cat-print, .cat-photography, .cat-identity").css('font-weight', 'normal')     
    $(".campaign").fadeTo(600, 4);
    $(".identity, .photography, .print").fadeTo(100, 0);
    $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
});

});
```

JS Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/XL3G3/5/

If you have taken a look, the last thing I can't work out is how to disable the hover function only on thumbnails that have been highlighted on category selection.

From what I've been trying to read up on, I have a feeling it may have something to do with event namespacing to enable me to bind and unbind the hover function? But I'm not sure, if someone could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciated it!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well - I have a solution for you:

When you do the hover function:

```
$('.box_print, .box_campaign, .box_identity, .box_photography').hover(function () {
        //when mouse hover over the wrapper div  
        //get it's children elements with class description '  
        //and show it using fadeTo  
        $(this).children('.print, .campaign, .identity, .photography').stop().fadeTo(300, 4);
    }, function () {
        //when mouse out of the wrapper div  
        //use fadeTo to hide the div  
        $(this).children('.print, .campaign, .identity, .photography').stop().fadeTo(0, 0);
    });
```

Instead of calling each of the thumbnails classes, like this:

```
$('.box_print, .box_campaign, .box_identity, .box_photography')
```

you can add the same class to all of the thumbnails, and do the hover function like this:

```
$('.box')
```

Then, when the user choose a category - remove `.box` class from all the thumbnails of the current category.

Comment: I forgot to mention, there is a colour assigned to each category which is why there are 4 different box classes.

Comment: @Kimberley - So you can just add a class to each div of category : `<div class="box_print box">` - It doesn't matter and will not change the div colour. (please mark it as answer if it helps you)